# Different result when deriving electric force as $dW/dr$ and $-dU/dr$

Tags: forces, electric-fields, work, potential-energy, conventions

Work done by electric field, $W$ is the negative of the change in electric potential energy, $U_r$.
$$W=-\Delta U$$
By considering an infinitesimal change in EPE, we can deduce that electric force, $F_e$ is the negative potential energy gradient.
$$-dU_r=F_e\cdot dr$$
$$-\frac{dU_r}{dr}=F_e$$
where
$$U_r=\frac{kQq}{r}$$
But from the first equation above, we can say that an infinitesimal change in EPE is the same as infinitesimal change in work.
$$dW=F_e\cdot dr$$
$$\frac{dW}{dr}=F_e$$
This contradicts with the first derivation as $W$ and $U_r$ both have the same equation, and the negative in the derivative is missing.
Work done by electric field to move a charge from r to $\infty$ :
$$W=-\Delta U_r=\int_{r}^{\infty}\frac{kQq}{r^2}dr$$
$$-(U_\infty - U_r)=\frac{kQq}{r}$$
$$U_r=\frac{kQq}{r}$$
$$W=U_r$$
Finding $F_e$,
$$-\frac{dU_r}{dr}=-\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{kQq}{r})=\frac{kQq}{r^2}$$
$$\frac{dW}{dr}=\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{kQq}{r})=-\frac{kQq}{r^2}$$

Comment: From $-dU_r / dr = F_e$ and $dW/dr = F_e$ it follows $-dU_r/dr = dW/dr$ which equals $dW = -dU_r$. This is exactly what you wrote in the first line $W = -\Delta U$. What do you mean by *"this contradicts with the first derivation as $W$ and $U_r$ both have the same equation"*?

Comment: $W$ and $U_r$ equals $\frac{kQq}{r}$, and by differentiating this, we get different equations of $F_e$, as the sign is different which is mathematically obvious as there is a missing negative sign in the derivative of work done.

Comment: This might be a possible reason:
$W=-\Delta U_r$, only $U_r$ can be express as a change, and we can then relate this to the derivative, whereas $W$ already means a change, so we don't write $dW$

Comment: Am I correct to assume that you are confused how come $W$ and $dW$ mean the same thing? If yes, then see the post below.

Comment: Who says that $W$ is the Coulomb potential? Anyways: When working with work, always make sure to inspect who performs work on whom before discussing the sign!

Comment: I can't find any question in your last edit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematics in your post is correct:

$$\text{from} \qquad F_e = -\frac{d U_r}{dr} \qquad \text{and} \qquad F_e = \frac{dW}{dr} \qquad \text{it follows} \qquad \boxed{dW = -dU_r} \tag 1$$

As you already mentioned, the work $W$ done by a conservative force equals the negative of the change in potential energy $\Delta U$

$$W = -\Delta U \tag 2$$

What is seems to me is that you are confused how come $dW$ in Eq. (1) and $W$ in Eq. (2) mean the same thing. Note that the well known equation for work

$$W = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} \tag 3$$

actually comes from

$$dW = \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} \tag 4$$

You can read the Eq. (4) as follows: a force $\vec{F}$ over infinitesimal small displacement $d\vec{r}$ does infinitesimal small work $dW$.

---

Responding to your edit, you are getting the wrong sign because independent variable $r$ in

> Work done by electric field to move a charge from r to $\infty$ :
> $$W=-\Delta U_r=\int_{r}^{\infty}\frac{kQq}{r^2}dr$$

is lower bound of the integral. Remember that by definition, if function $f$ is continuous on interval $[a,x]$ then

$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt \quad \rightarrow \quad F'(x) = f(x)$$

But in your case you have

$$F(x) = \int_{x}^{a} f(t) dt = - \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt \quad \rightarrow \quad -F'(x) = f(x)$$

The expression for work done by electric field to move a charge from $r$ to $\infty$ that you found

> $$U_r = \frac{k Q q}{r}$$
> $$W = U_r$$

is correct. But when you take derivate of that expression to find force $F_e$, you have to take into account that $r$ was actually lower bound.

Comment: $W_{\rm final}-W_{\rm initial}$ has no meaning in Physics.

Comment: @Farcher You are right, better not to use (final) and (initial) in the context of work.